# Method 'SetValueForUICulture' don't set other language value

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a problem with SetValueForUICulture method in my PowerShell script, I added field using method Add-PnPField and later according to what I found on the internet I tried use SetValueForUICulture method to change other language title (TitleResource).

Unfortunately after run script don't see changes, method GetValueForUICulture('example') return empty "Value". My attempts are as follows:

*Of course, when the fields already exist:

```
$myField = Get-PnPField -Identity "AssignedTo"
$myField.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture("pl-pl", "Example title")
$myField.Update() or $myField.UpdateAndPushChanges($true) 
later using

$myField.TitleResource.GetValueForUICulture('pl-pl')
```

and return

[image]

please help, i searched all... :/

Comment: Does it work if you call `$myField = Get-PnPField -Identity "AssignedTo"` again after `UpdateAndPushChanges()`?

Comment: Ok, problem is loose, the code looks like this:

`$node = Get-PnPField -List $listName -Identity "example"
$node.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture("en-us", "example")
$node.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)`

later check changes:
`# $ResourceEntries = $node.TitleResource.GetResourceEntries()
# Invoke-PnPQuery
# $ResourceEntries
`

Comment: If you've found a solution on your own, then please post an answer below (don't use comments to post answers)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem is loose, the code looks like this:

```
$node = Get-PnPField -List $listName -Identity "example" 
$node.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture("en-us", "example") 
$node.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
```

later check changes:

```
$ResourceEntries = $node.TitleResource.GetResourceEntries()
Invoke-PnPQuery
$ResourceEntries
```